# add string in resource in android

Tags: android, resources, autocompletetextview

I have a String array in resource file

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Albania</item>
        <item>Algeria</item>
        <item>American Samoa</item>
        <item>Andorra</item>
        <item>Angola</item>
        <item>Anguilla</item>
        <item>Antarctica</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

`

I want to add Name from my Database / for now think of from Activity.java file
is there any way to do that ?

I want to use them in my AutoCompleteTextView for HINT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add things programatically to a resource.  They're hard coded at compile time.  What you can do is read in the resource, store it in a List, and then add to that.

Comment: Then how to make an dynamic auto complete text view so that in admin pannel when there is a new user login their licence Number can be shown as a hint !?

Comment: The adapter for the autocomplete doesn't need to work on a resource.  In fact you almost never use one unless all the options are predefined.